# How do i fix this JS scope in GM_xmlhttpRequest

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, scope

When i run this code alert 2 shows 6 different href links. alert 3 shows the last href 6 times. How do i make it use the same object (linkdom aka thelink) as alert 2.

NOTE: This is in a greasemonkey script

```
    {
        var linkdom = thelink;
        alert('2' + linkdom.getAttribute("href"));
        GM_xmlhttpRequest({
            method: 'GET',
            url: href,
            onload: function(resp){
                //...
                alert('3' + linkdom.getAttribute("href"));
            }
        });
    //...
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this were your own function, I'd say to pass it in as a parameter. Or if JavaScript had default parameters, I'd say pass it in as a default parameter. The way it is now, though... try this.

```
{
    var linkdom = thelink;
    alert('2' + linkdom.getAttribute("href"));        
    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
        method: 'GET',
        url: href,
        onload: (function() { 
              var localvar = linkdom; 
              return function(resp){
                //...
                alert('3' + localvar.getAttribute("href"));
              }})()
    });
//...
}
```

This creates an outer function and sets a local variable to the current value of `linkdom`. It then creates your function and returns it. I then immediately apply the outer function to get your function back. The outer functions won't share the same local variable, so the code should work.

Comment: i've seen this pattern before, except `linkdom` is passed to the inline function as a parameter, rather than having the inline function close over it. is there any difference between the two?

Comment: im not sure. i think the effect is the same - create a local variable with what you want in it. this way is a bit clearer to me since you can see what goes into `localvar` more clearly